# Coupled nonlinear ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

\begin{align*}
2A'+3A^2\bar{A}&=0\\
2\bar{A}'+3\bar{A}^2A&=0
\end{align*}
with ICs $:A(0)=-\frac{\textit{i}}{2}, \bar{A}(0)=\frac{i}{2}$

The solution is given \begin{align*}A(t)=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{4+3t}}\\\bar{A}(t)=\frac{i}{\sqrt{4+3t}}
\end{align*}

How was this solution calculated?

Comment: Note that $2A'\overline{A} - 2A\overline{A}' = 0$ which implies that $\overline{A}/A = -1$ (constant $-1$ follows from the IC). This simplifies the system down to one equation $2A' = 3A^3$ which is easier to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|A|^2=2Re(\bar AA')=3Re(\bar A^2A^2)=3|A|^4
$$
Thus
$$
|A|^2=\frac{1}{|A(0)|^{-2}+3t}=\frac1{4+3t}
$$
Now insert this into the first equation
$$
2A'=3|A|^2A=\frac{3}{4+3t}A
$$
and solve as linear or separable equation.